# API planning for User Authentication and API protection for a mobile app

Tags: c#, android, ios, security, authentication

I am currently planning out an API build (C# MVC Web API) specifically for an iOS + Android app. With this app, users will be able to sign-in to an account they create on our system (not allowing OpenID accounts such as Google/Facebook at this time). They will only have to login to the app one time (think Snapchat, Facebook, Uber, etc).

The communication between API and app will be secured with HTTPS.

What I'm trying to figure out are the following two things:

**Do I have the app submit username + password on every API call that requires authentication, or look to using a token based system?**

What benefit would a token based system offer me if the app is infrequently accessed and the app will not be needing to authenticate with other systems outside of this API?

Why wouldn't I want to just submit username + password on each call?

**How to I 'attempt' to protect the API from unauthorized access?**

I know that someone could root their phone, and decode the program to provide them with the capability of discovering the API through monitoring the API calls, thus giving them external access to the API. I also know that providing one API Key used on anyone's device is not very secure. From what I've seen, the best method is providing a unique API key to everyone who downloads the app.

The next question here though if this is the case, wouldn't the app then need to supply the API key on every call? Thus, the API would need to not only verify username + password, but also verify the API key on every transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely use a token-based system. OAuth is a token system and you will be glad in the future, even if for no other reason than using the standard.

Using a token system allows you to avoid storing the user's credentials on the device. You should never, ever store a decryptable version of the user's password, anywhere. A token system will still require you to store a secret on the user's device - the auth token - but it's a less privileged secret: your servers know that it's attached to a particular device, and more importantly it's revokable at any time without affecting the user's other devices.

As for protecting the API - don't bother. Design your API so that it'd be secure, even if it were public. You cannot rely on user devices to give you trusted information, even if your app isn't compromised. Always, always, ALWAYS validate and double check incoming data, especially if it's coming from a device you don't physically control.